# Is $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ a $G_\delta$ set?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, the-baire-space

I can prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}$. I was applying the same Baire space argument to show that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_\delta$ set.

I was thinking like this:

We can write $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q})^c= \displaystyle{\bigcap_{(p,q)\in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}}\{(p,q)\}^c}= \displaystyle{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n}$ where each $V_n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If we can write $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}= \displaystyle{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n}$ where each $U_n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(U_n \cap V_n)}= \phi$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$-----which is a contradiction.!

Am I thinking correctly ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you can prove that $\Bbb Q$ is **not** a $G_\delta$ set?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (You should correct the first sentence of the question.) Yes, the argument for $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is the same as the argument for $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, since $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Comment: Oh right thanks. that was a typo error.

Comment: I figured that it probably was.

Comment: Yes. Any complete metric space is a Baire space. Another method uses 2 theorems: (1). If $Y$ is a non-empty complete metric space with no isolated points then $Y$ has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set $C$, so $|Y|\ge |C|=2^{\aleph_0}$. (2). If $Y$ is a subspace of a complete metric space $X$ then the subspace topology on $Y$ can be generated by a complete metric on $Y$ iff $Y$ is a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X$. These are proved without the Baire theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument for $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is exactly the same as for $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, in essence:

If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space with no isolated points then any countable dense set $D$ is not a $G_\delta$:

Suppose $D=\bigcap_n O_n$, where all $O_n$ are open. It follows that the $O_n$ are dense too as they all contain the dense set $D$.

Also, $X\setminus \{d\}$ is open and dense for any $d \in D$ as there are no isolated points.

But then $$\emptyset= D \cap D^\complement = \bigcap_n O_n \cap \bigcap_{d \in D} (X\setminus \{d\}$$

contradicts the Baire theorem for the complete $(X,d)$: a countable intersection of dense open sets with empty (not dense!) intersection.

$\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$ is still countable and dense and $\Bbb R^2$ is complete metric without isolated points so the same proof applies.